# No of page likes for a facebook page for particular daterange

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to find no of page likes for  different pages in a date range. I tried different method like page_fans_country/lifetime to know but i don't think that's correct api call to get this information.

Right now i am able to know the likes of page at present but i like to know likes for a page in past 15 days.

```
$app_result                     = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=[APP_ID]&client_secret=[APP_SECRET]&grant_type=client_credentials');

$access_token                   = trim(str_replace("access_token=","",$app_result));

$result                         = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_page_link.'?access_token='.$access_token);
$data                           = json_decode($result,true);
```

Can any one point me in right direction to get this information.

Comment: Sidenote: Application id and secret are for private use .. not to distribute them in public ..

Comment: I get it sorry i forgot while posting it. Any way can you help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[PAGE_ID]/insights/page_fans?since=[2014-01-01]&until=[2014-02-01]&access_token=[ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

The only limitation is the daterange cannot be bigger than 35 days.

[image]

Comment: there was no such method called page_fans in graph api at all. I am trying in graph explorer directly to see the result.

Comment: `page_fans` in this case is a so-called `metric` for the `insights` endpoint, so this is correct

Comment: no it's not giving any result the above call try in graph api explorer

Comment: @Venkat: You should be able to read the insights of that particular page.. as insights of pages are not public.. try getting 'read_insights' extended permission and then fetching results using graph explorer

Comment: did you own that page for the page which you are trying

Comment: Yes.. I already cleared that to you that "You should be able to read the insights of that particular page.. as insights of pages are not public"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57254/discussion-between-venkat-and-syed-qarib).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the `page_fans` metric is only available to page owners or people with the respective privileges. So it's not working to get the `insights` from any page, but only for those which you administer.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/insights/page_fans?since=2014-06-15&until=2014-07-14&period=period(%27day%27)&access_token={page_or_user_access_token}
```

If you own the page, you can use the `read_insights` permission to grant the access right to the data, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/insights/#reading

If you're not the owner of the pages, the only chance you have is to recurrently read the `likes`data from the individual `page` object (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page#readfields) on a daily basis to generate the stats by yourself:

```
/{page_id}?fields=id,likes
```

The gathering of historical data is not possible with this method.

Comment: how you are getting the last 5 days also for pages which you don't own

Comment: Read what I wrote: It's not possible!

Comment: how these guys showing the likes of behance website page without owning that page
http://www.startupranking.com/behance

Comment: How they are getting then

Comment: What? The stats? Like I wrote, query the data every day for the specific day and storing the results to a database.